# Unexpected exception, expected<javax.mail.MessagingException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException>

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, jakarta-mail, testcase

I am trying to implement mail service (org.springframework.mail.javamail), functionality is  working absolutely fine however while writing unit test cases with **mockito5 not powermockito**, i am not able to cover  `catch(MessagingException e) and catch(IOException e)`

[image]

This is the piece of implementation code `UsageReportBillingMailService.java`

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UsageReportBillingMailService {

    @Value("${mail_receivers.mail_to:''}")
    private String[] mailToList;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    @Autowired
    private IUsageReportBillingRepository billingRepository;

    public void send(String period) {
        try {
            log.info("{} Getting usage billing report from DB ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
            UsageReportBilling billingReportForPeriod = billingRepository.findByPeriod(period);
            if (billingReportForPeriod == null) {
                log.error("{} Cannot get the report from DB ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
                throw new ReportNotFoundException(UsageReportConstants.REPORT_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            String reportHeader = UsageReportConstants.BILLING_REPORT_CSV_HEADER;
            String reportContent = billingReportForPeriod.getPeriod() + UsageReportConstants.COMMA +
                    billingReportForPeriod.getDeviceCount() + UsageReportConstants.COMMA +
                    billingReportForPeriod.getStorageUsed() + UsageReportConstants.COMMA +
                    billingReportForPeriod.getApiSuccessCount() + UsageReportConstants.COMMA +
                    billingReportForPeriod.getApiFailCount() + UsageReportConstants.COMMA +
                    billingReportForPeriod.getEventCount();

            File attachmentFile = generateAttachmentFile(UsageReportConstants.BILLING_REPORT_FILE_NAME_PREFIX + period, UsageReportConstants.CSV_FILE_EXT, reportHeader.concat("\n" + reportContent));
            prepareMail(mailToList, UsageReportConstants.MAIL_FROM, UsageReportConstants.MAIL_SUBJECT + " " + period, UsageReportConstants.MAIL_BODY + " " + period, attachmentFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("{} Cannot create attachment file ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error("{} if multipart creation failed ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
        }
    }

    private File generateAttachmentFile(String fileName, String fileType, String fileContent) throws IOException {
        log.info("{} Generating File from content for mail attachment ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
        byte[] outputBytes = fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, fileType, null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.write(outputBytes);
        return tempFile;
    }

    private void prepareMail(String[] toList, String from, String mailSubject, String mailBody, File attachment) throws MessagingException {
        log.info("{} Preparing mail and sending to listed recipient ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setSubject(mailSubject);
        helper.setText(mailBody);
        helper.setTo(toList);
        helper.setFrom(from);
        helper.addAttachment(attachment.getName(), attachment);
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

for which i am trying to cover in Junit test case `UsageReportBillingMailServiceTest.java`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UsageReportBillingMailServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UsageReportBillingMailService usageReportBillingMailService;

    @Mock
    private UsageReportBilling usageReportBilling;

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    @Mock
    private IUsageReportBillingRepository usageReportBillingRepository;

    private String period = "2020-06";

    @Test
    public void verifySendEmail() {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(usageReportBillingMailService, "mailToList", new String[]{"info@testmail.com", "info@testmail.com"});
        Mockito.when(usageReportBillingRepository.findByPeriod(period)).thenReturn(buildUsageReportBilling());
        Mockito.when(emailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        usageReportBillingMailService.send(period);
        Assert.assertNull(null);
    }


    @Test(expected = ReportNotFoundException.class)
    public void verifySendEmailWhenReportNotFoundExceptionThrown() {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
        Mockito.when(usageReportBillingRepository.findByPeriod("2029-01")).thenReturn(null);
        usageReportBillingMailService.send(period);
        Assert.assertNull(" ReportNotFound Exception Expected ");
    }

/*
 // this is not working
    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void verifySendEmailWhenIOExceptionThrown() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = Mockito.mock(FileOutputStream.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(usageReportBillingMailService, "mailToList", new String[]{"info@testmail.com", "info@testmail.com"});
        Mockito.when(usageReportBillingRepository.findByPeriod(period)).thenReturn(buildUsageReportBilling());
        Mockito.doThrow(new IOException("this")).when(usageReportBillingMailService).send(period);
        usageReportBillingMailService.send(period);
        Assert.assertNull(" IOException Expected ");
    }

 // this is not working
    @Test(expected = MessagingException.class)
    public void verifySendEmailWhenMessagingExceptionThrown() throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(usageReportBillingMailService, "mailToList", new String[]{"info@testmail.com", "info@testmail.com"});
        Mockito.when(usageReportBillingRepository.findByPeriod(period)).thenReturn(buildUsageReportBilling());
        Mockito.when(emailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        Mockito.doThrow(new MessagingException("this")).when(usageReportBillingMailService).send(period);
        usageReportBillingMailService.send(period);
        Assert.assertNull(" MessagingException Expected ");
    }
*/

    private UsageReportBilling buildUsageReportBilling() {
        UsageReportBilling billingReport = new UsageReportBilling();
        billingReport.setPeriod(period);
        billingReport.setDeviceCount(100L);
        billingReport.setStorageUsed(10000L);
        billingReport.setApiSuccessCount(1000L);
        billingReport.setApiFailCount(10L);
        billingReport.setEventCount(0L);
        return billingReport;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the `send()` throw `MessagingException`? It throws `MailException` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html#send-javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage...-

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: @JavaTechnical, yes JavaMailSender  send() throws MailException but may I know how can i cover MessagingException  in test case? also MailException

Comment: Where in your code is `MessagingException` thrown? Mock that method call.

Comment: @JavaTechnical, `MimeMessageHelper` throws `MessagingException`  ?

Comment: @JavaTechnical, I have added entire code here, could you please check what is wrong?

Comment: See the answer, you can create a method that creates this object and mock that method call.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in the test case you shown us:

- you only prepare your mocks, but never call any method from object under test.
- you throw incorrect exception type from `emailSender.send(message);`

I hope that the first is clear and is only a result of editing the SO post.

For the second one: The message you receive is clear about the reason of the error:

```
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: javax.mail.MessagingException: this
```

When mocking a method, you cannot throw a checked exception that is not declared in the method's signature. This restrictions shouldn't come as a surprise - when implementing a method, the same restriction applies.

You can check that MessagingException is not thrown by [JavaMailSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html).
All exceptions that methods of this class can throw are unchecked.

In particular, MailException is unchecked:

```
void send(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MailException
```

To solve:

- if you intend to catch MailException as well, throw it when mocking `emailSender.send(message)`
- If you need to provoke `MessagingException` to be thrown, you should do it in a point where it can actually be thrown - in the methods of [MimeMessageHelper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html).
  For example, setting an invalid address in `setTo` or `setFrom` throws AddressException, which is a subtype of MessagingException

To give you head start:

```
var mm = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
var mh = new MimeMessageHelper(mm);
mh.setTo("@INVALID_EMAIL");
```

throws:

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Missing local name
 in string ``@INVALID_EMAIL''
```

Comment: Yes, I tried using throws as well :( Sorry I am new to this but I read somewhere that throws and catch does the same thing. still getting same error that is why not posted that code here.

Comment: 1. "I tried using throws": it is unclear what you attempted without seeing your code. 2. "throws and catch does the same thing": this is simply not true.

Comment: I have updated my question and added entire code, Could you please check ?

Comment: I am throwing it from the private methods and catching it in called public method

Comment: You posted your code, but still didn't apply my advice. I can still see `Mockito.doThrow(new MessagingException("this")).when(usageReportBillingMailService).send(period);` in your test code.

Comment: mimeMessageHelper.setTo("@INVALID_EMAIL"); this is throwing AssetError

Comment: See the docs (are we talking about the same method?): https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setTo-java.lang.String-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216819/discussion-between-sujay-and-lesiak).

Answer (score 0):

`MessagingException` is thrown while creating the `MimeMessageHelper` object. So you can create a method that creates this object and mock that method call to throw this exception.

```
UsageReportBillingMailService current = this;

private void prepareMail(String[] toList, String from, String mailSubject, String mailBody, File attachment) throws MessagingException {
    log.info("{} Preparing mail and sending to listed recipient ", UsageReportConstants.USAGE_REPORT_BILLING_MAIL_SERVICE_LOG);
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = current.createMimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setSubject(mailSubject);
    helper.setText(mailBody);
    helper.setTo(toList);
    helper.setFrom(from);
    helper.addAttachment(attachment.getName(), attachment);
    emailSender.send(message);
}

MimeMessageHelper createMimeMessageHelper(MimeMessage message, boolean multipart) {
    return new MimeMessageHelper(message, multipart);
}
```

In the Test

```
    when(mocked.createMimeMessageHelper(any(MimeMessage.class), anyBoolean())
    .thenThrow(new MessagingException("test"));
    FieldSetter.setField(usageReportBillingMailServiceInstance, UsageReportBillingMailService.class.getDeclaredField("current"), mocked);
    usageReportBillingMailServiceInstance.prepareMessage(...)
```